Beginner question: Plotting frequency spectrum of a discrete spectrum using Matlab?
First, I apologize for the repost, I got really confused how Stack Exchange works. I tried my best to improve the question!
Anyhow - I'm fairly new to the world of DSP, and I'm struggling with finding a way to plot the frequency spectrum of a discrete signal I calculated, described by
$$x(k) = 4 \left(\frac{\sin(4\pi k/6)}{4\pi k/6}\right)^2$$
with $x(0)=2$
using Matlab.
I have so far tried 4 different solutions, only one of which looks plausible, but I'd like to be sure. I know it's probably solved using the fft function, but I can't quite put it together.
Could someone help me figure this out? It'd be greatly appreciated!
Edit: As kindly suggested - and I really should have thought of it -- this is the Matlab code I'm currently working with:
k = -12:12;

x_k = 4 * (sin(4 * pi * k / 6) ./ (4 * pi * k / 6)).^2;
x_k(k == 0) = 2; 

X_f = fftshift(fft(x_k));

f = linspace(-0.5, 0.5, length(k));  

figure;
stem(f, abs(X_f), 'filled');
title('Frequency Spectrum of the Discrete Signal x(k)');
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('Magnitude');
grid on;

And this is a picture of the resulting spectrum:


Hi! As I had commented in your now-deleted previous question, please show what you’ve tried (your “plausible” solution). Add your Matlab code at least, and even better also a picture of the resulting spectrum. To do so, use “edit” at the bottom of your question

I think you code does what you want it to do. If you recognize the mathematical equation, you might recognize it is actually a sinc function. So, it would be a fun exercise by playing with different parameters to see how the plot/shape of the wave changes with changing different parameters.

Use the code below, here Ts = 1/Fs, where Ts is the sampling time of your signal and L is the number of points in your signal
Y = fft(X);
    P2 = abs(Y/L);
        P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
        P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
        
        f = Fs/L*(0:(L/2));
        plot(f,P1,"LineWidth",3) 
        title("Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of X(t)")
        xlabel("f (Hz)")
        ylabel("|P1(f)|")

Source: https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

1.-
You have chosen an input caridnal sin , the famous sinc function with 1st null at f0=2/3 Hz.
Because sin(4*pi*k/6) = sinc (4/6)
2.-
It's always useful to define the time step dt and the sampling frequency Fs .
Both come handy when going from 2-side spectrum produced by fft to 1-side spectrum, as well as to calculate all the frequency points.
So here we go
dt=.01;
Fs=1/dt;
t = [-12:dt:12];

f0=1/3;

% x = 2*(sin(2*pi*f0*t)./(2*pi*f0*t)).^2;
x = 2*(sinc(f0*t)).^2;

% x(end)=[];   % even amount of time samples
L=numel(x);

figure(1);     % time domain
ax1=gca
plot(ax1,x)
title(ax1,['x(t)   f0 = ' num2str(f0) ' Hz'])
xlabel(ax1,'t[s]');


X=fft(x,numel(x));
absX=abs(X);

% 1-side 
P2=abs(X/L);
P1=P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);

% calculating frequencies
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;

figure(2)     % frequency domain
ax2=gca
plot(ax2,f,P1) 
title(ax2,'Single-Sided |X(f)|')
xlabel(ax2,'f [Hz]')
ylabel(ax2,'|P1(f)|')
grid(ax2,'on');


3.-
You may have already obtained the correct spectrum but it may have been stuck to the Y axis.
Try for instance f0=30
Now the signal x in time domain looks quite sharp

and in frequency domain the spectrum is clearly visible, no longer stuck on Y axis

Additiona Comments
4.-
To do x(0)=2 you just have to change the value in of the squared sinc front 4 to 2.
The reason
fun1=@(t) sinc(t).^2  % sinc(t)=sin(pi*t)/(pi*t)
integral(fun1,-Inf,Inf)

is
 =
   0.999999998051721

the area under a squared sinc from -Inf to Inf is already 1.
5.-
For whatever reason the direct definition of x as x=2*(sin(2*pi*f0*t)./(2*pi*f0*t)).^2
when through fft returns a bunch of NaN (Not a Number) nonsense.
Just use MATLAB function sinc instead . Function sinc was defined to avoid some particular f0 messing with too-close-to-zero or divide-by-zero errors that may end up producingNaN when obviously should be numerical values indeed.
6.-
The stem graph included in question may be X spectrum of x but DC shifted up by 1, which makes it infinite energy.
While the sinc (aka cardinal sin) input signal has finite energy.
